# Evenly-spaced 1/freq for R function spec.pgram()

Tags: r, spectrum

The goal is to plot of the coherency between two time series (i.e. the correlation coefficient with respect to frequencies). How can I get 1/freq (i.e. the period) in the x-axis to be evenly-spaced?

```
t <- 0:99
ts1 <- ts(2*cos((2*pi)/24*t))
ts2 <- ts(2*cos((2*pi)/48*t))
ts12 <- ts.intersect(ts1, ts2)

Coh <- spec.pgram(ts12, spans=3)
plot(Coh$freq, Coh$coh, type='l')
plot(1/Coh$freq, Coh$coh, type='l')  # how to get 1/freq to be evenly-space?
```

I have tried to modify the function spec.pgram() but without success. More specifically, I replace the line:

```
freq <- seq.int(from = xfreq/N, by = xfreq/N, length.out = Nspec)
```

with:

```
freq.tmp <- seq.int(from = xfreq/N, by = xfreq/N, length.out = Nspec)
freq <- rev(1/seq(from=1/max(freq.tmp), to=1/min(freq.tmp), length.out=Nspec))
```

Has anyone else had better luck? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you just want to relabel the x-axis with periods, rather than frequencies? That would maintain the spacing of the values on the x-axis, at the expense of a non-linear scaling for the x values. For example (using `ggplot2`):

```
library(ggplot2)

dat = as.data.frame(Coh[c("freq","spec","coh","phase")])

ggplot(dat, aes(freq, coh)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=dat$freq[seq(1,nrow(dat),3)], 
                     minor_breaks=dat$freq,
                     labels=round(1/dat$freq[seq(1,nrow(dat),3)],1)) +
  labs(x="Period")
```

[image]

You could also set the x-value labels to fall on integer periods:

```
breaks = c(1:10,15,25,50,100)

ggplot(dat, aes(freq, coh)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1/breaks,
                     minor_breaks = 1/(breaks[-1] - 0.5 * diff(breaks)),
                     labels=breaks) +
  labs(x="Period")
```

[image]

Comment: well done eipi10, i think that's a correct solution! Cheers

Comment: Although it would be nicer to have the linear scaling, or 'evenly-spaced' feature

Comment: Well, the linear scaling is what you get when you plot 1/freq directly. But that's what you were trying to avoid.

Comment: The modification I made returns evenly-spaced periods (by specifying unevenly-spaced frequencies), but the output (the coherence, as a function of periods) doesn't look right (it doesn't look like a stretching version of your plots). I suspect there's something about spectral theory that was missing